# Answers written in "joke" languages

Tags: discussion, policy, answers, rules, deleted-answers

As an answer to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101638/41505), I wrote an [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101685/41505) in the "programming language" 2014 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oW6O.jpg)). The answer was deleted, accompanied with this note:

> I'm temporarily removing this post in compliance with our [policy about answers not meeting the challenge specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/12012). Please feel free to edit your answer and to flag it for moderator attention so it can be undeleted.

I understand if joke programming languages were outright banned, but I've seen them be used effectively to solve specific challenges before. My confusion essentially boils down to two questions:

1) What are the limits for these kinds of languages? For answers like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59497/41505), it is pretty clear that when the language is used creatively, it is allowed.

2) What kind of edit would I be able to make to have the answer undeleted without changing the essence of the answer?

Comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073

2014 is definitely not a programming language. Just because other answers don't follow the rules and don't get deleted doesn't mean that you don't have to follow them. On the other hand, I think your answer is intresting and should be kept, though non-competing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of [*What are programming languages?*](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages), though [*Definitive policy about answers not meeting the challenge specification*](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7987/definitive-policy-about-answers-not-meeting-the-challenge-specification) would also be a good dupe target. Both of those have answers that answer this question.

Comment: @Mego Maybe they have an answer to question 1, but they don't really go near question 2

Comment: @DanielM. Sure they do: use a real programming language

Comment: @Mego If I change the programming language, it becomes a different answer. I might as well just post a new answer. Anyways, I wouldn't feel comfortable keeping the upvotes made on a _fundamentally different_ answer. "Edit" implies that it's possible to have a 'good' answer without changing the whole point of the answer.

Comment: @DanielM. The point was not that you should edit the deleted answer to use a different language - it's that you shouldn't have made an answer using a joke language in the first place. But you did, and it got deleted. There's no way to salvage it.

Comment: @Mego Not according to the original moderator comment on the answer. Which brings us back to question 2

Comment: @DanielM. The moderator comment is a canned response. Every answer that gets deleted for not complying with the specification or site-wide rules gets that exact same comment. Some answers are salvageable. This one is not.

Comment: It should also be noted that although the language has an esolangs page, and it's in the category "Implemented", I cannot find the interpreter.

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm pretty sure it was implemented in some IRC bot. If an implementation is necessary, I'll be happy to provide one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) What are the limits for these kinds of languages? For answers like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/59497/41505), it is pretty clear that when the language is used creatively, it is allowed.

That isn't clear to me at all. My (personal) opinion is that the post uses a non-programming language, so creative or not, it isn't valid. I won't delete it unilaterally though.

In general, *post X wasn't deleted so it is valid* is a [broken-window argument](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124635/170332). I deleted *your* post because it was flagged for moderator attention. If it hadn't been, I would probably have missed it.

> 2) What kind of edit would I be able to make to have the answer undeleted without changing the essence of the answer?

This is my standard response when I delete answers, and I mention editing in case the affected user isn't aware that he can still edit mod-deleted answers. Apologies for the confusion. However, if you happen to know a different language that solves this task in zero bytes, you could fix your answer *without* changing the essence.

That said, there is no rule that says you cannot change "the essence" of an answer. Soft-deleted answers are forever visible to users with [access to moderator tools](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), so unless there's a compelling reason to post a new answer instead of editing a deleted one, the latter is preferable.

Comment: I would say that drastically changing the content of an answer is a compelling reason to post a new answer rather than editing and undeleting an existing one. Since users who voted on the answer won't know if/when it gets deleted without actively stalking the post, their votes likely won't be changed, which means that that answer has votes on it from when it was a completely different answer, and the voters would likely vote differently (especially in the case of downvotes).

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought we decided that [answering in a non-programming language was allowed](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10426/20198).

Comment: @NathanMerrill I don't think a **+16/-6** answer is enough to overthrow [an established consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/12012) that currently stands at **+59/-4**.

Comment: 59/-4 is over a long period of time, and it didn't really present any alternatives. The point of the post *was* to establish a consensus despite multiple conflicting posts