# Partially Valid Answers

Tags: discussion

Recently I posted an answer that handled all but one part of a question. (It was an answer to 'You had me at hello' that could not handle infinite input. I was approached by a moderator and told to take it down because it did not properly answer the question (which I agree with). I eventually deleted it.

I would have marked it as non-competing, but it was in a language created before the challenge posting.

So here is my question: should we have a way to have partially valid answers? If so, what?

Comment: In addition to the dupe target, [this post is also relevant.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7987/8478)